# Div invisible in ie but not in ff and chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, ie-developer-tools

I have a couple of web pages with css'. When I open the index page in chrome and firefox, there is no error. However when I open in internet explorer, one division will be invisible.
Although I see that division in source code,  when I open it by the developer tools in ie, I can not see it there. What can be the error?

Comment: You have a syntax issue.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Some HTML/CSS would be appreciated.

Comment: I can not post the code cause it is more than 400 lines.
How could it be that source code is seen but developer tools can not see?

Comment: @Alock examples: you forgot some closing tag; left `script` or `style` tags open i.e. without `</script>` or `</style>` tags; misusing the developer tools (div is there but in other place than you expect) and the div is hidden due to some CSS rule. Without relevant code chances to really help you are really slim.

Comment: Also, when posting comment on someone else comment use `@` to notify him/her (one at a time) otherwise they'll never know you commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your web page have a DTD ?  Do you still have the problem if your DTD is XHTML strict ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

IE is well known to be wildly off the standards for compatibility reasons to support pages written in the mesozoic era of IE4 and IE5 when MS thought they would rule the web over the W3C.  To make sure IE is more respectful of the standards, use this DTD and there should be little cross browser issues between MSHTML, Gecko and Webkit browsers.

Comment: Hmm... you mean <!DOCTYPE HTML>. HTML5 FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Every browser receives a copy of the whole client-side source code. Sadly, Internet Explorer (IE) is lagging behind when it comes to implementing standard functionalities. For this reason, IE will not always interpret your code correctly. In fact, it will interpret the code in the way it believes it is right and not the right standard way of doing it.

For a long time, Microsoft has thought that it could be above the web standards because it has the monopoly of the market shares. This is slowly changing though. Perhaps, the expected standard compliant features of IE9 reflects the market shares loss for Microsoft in the browser wars.

Still, a great majority of users are not aware or care about browser functionality. They are more likely to not upgrade to IE9 when it comes out. Therefore, I suggest that you add the following markup in your HTML document header:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">`

You can find more info about this [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/faq.html). Thank you Google!!

**It would be interesting to see the faulty source code...**

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem at all.

Comment: @Alerty: That tag is for forcing IE8 to use the rendering engine of earlier versions of IE - it does nothing when you specify Chrome.

Comment: @Karpie: Have you even read the QA on the Google Chrome Frame from the link I provided?

Comment: @Alerty: I have, but requiring users of a public website to have a specific browser plugin installed to view your site properly is ridiculous.

Comment: @Karpie: We could argue a lot on the subject. http://www.bringdownie6.com/ and http://www.dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: @Alerty: We could. Yet I notice both of those links make no reference to Chrome Frame. I'm all for getting rid of IE6, and progressive enhancement, but I dislike the idea of Chrome Frame, plus it's overkill for what is probably a one line CSS fix to the issue at hand.

Comment: @Karpie: By the way, how would you answer this question without the help of any source code? ;)

Comment: @Karpie: If the code works in Chrome like Alock Leo said then it will work with the Chrome Frame. Without any other information, it is hard to give a better answer than what Alain Pannetier wrote or I wrote.

Comment: @Alerty: I wouldn't answer it, hence I haven't.

Comment: @Karpie: In fact, this could fix in part the current problem. I would agree with you if you would say that it is not the best possible solution, but it works. In my opinion, the downvote was not necessary.

Comment: @Alerty: I wouldn't consider it a solution at all.